# Error in parameters to LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#stop-updates) example from http://developer.android.com to get location updates. I get the following error when trying to call the `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates()` method. Please help me resolve this.

[image]

When I let `Android Studio` fix the issue for me, it does the following:
[image]
This, however, results in the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew! I had forgotten to implement the `LocationListener` class in my `activity.java` like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution was import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
and delete import android.location.LocationListener;